# CSS3 Keyframes & Transforms not a displaying a cube properly

Tags: html, css, transform, keyframe

I'm trying to get the CSS to display a 3D cube.

I have a fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/t89v1grs/)**.

The top and bottom of the cube don't have any text, but the sides do. Each side has a single line of text.

Here is my "side" class...

```
.side {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

And individual classes for specific sides...

```
.back {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) rotate&(180deg);
}

.right {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY (-270deg) translateX(100px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
}

.left {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY (270deg) translateX(-100px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
}

.top {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
}

.bottom {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
}

.front {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've just some slight issues with spaces and not closing brackets. If you add the `)` where you set the color for `.side` and remove the spaces between your `rotateY` and `(270deg)` you should get a proper cube.

Here's a quick fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tsz85gfd/

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your CSS sintax (some spaces, brackets...): [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t89v1grs/1/)

```
body {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    font-family:'Questrial', sans-serif;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
/* Cube Wrapper */
 .cube-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 500;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
}
/* Cube Rotation */
 @-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
/* Cube */
 .cube {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    /* Determines if element's children are positioned in 3D space of flattened. */
    -webkit-animation: spin 4s infinite linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}
/* Cube Sides */
 .side {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}
.back {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
}
.right {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
}
.left {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
}
.top {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
}
.bottom {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
}
.front {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
}
/* Typing Animation */
 @-webkit-keyframs typing {
    from {
        width: 0
    }
    to {
        width: 7em
    }
}
/* Blinking Cursor */
 @-webkit-keyframes blink {
    from, to {
        border-color: transparent
    }
    50% {
        border-color: black
    }
}
/* Logo Text */
 .logo_text {
    position: absolute;
    top: -70px;
    left: 350px;
    font-family:'Questrial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: .1em solid black;
    line-height: 1px;
    /* Animates the cursor */
    -webkit-animation: typing 2s steps (13, end), blink 1s step-end infinite;
}
.logo_text .green {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
}
```